# How do I show/autofill all properties of a subschema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have the following json schema:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "$id": "http://example.com/schemas/example",
    "type": "object",
    "title": "example service",
    "properties": {
        "dependencies": {
            "type": "array",
            "required": [
                "items"
            ],
            "minItems": 1,
            "items": {
                "anyOf": [{
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/resource1"
                    },
                    {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/another_resource"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "resource1": {
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "requiredProperty": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                        "requiredValue"
                    ]
                },
                "notRequiredProperty": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "required": [
                    "requiredProperty"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my code editor, when I add the below, i get a message that says i can choose to autofill all required properties, which is great. But what I am looking for is a way for a user to *see* all the properties available to them. Is this a code editor thing? Or is this something JSON schema just doesn't handle?

```
dependencies:
  - type: requiredValue
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a code editor issue.  [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/) is just the schema format.  Other tooling such as linting and code completion is built on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

[JSONBuddy](https://json-buddy.com) provides a list of possible properties while editing your JSON data. There is a separate window with a list of properties together with an inline entry-helper while typing property names.